# Writing to file with uneven formats - python

Tags: python, format, writefile

I am trying to write a .dat file from an array I created in Python. Essentially, I want the second line of the file (picture attached) to look like: first 3 numbers in scientific notation w/ 6 numbers after the decimal and the last 2 numbers to be integers. Is there a quick way to do this in Python? I know in MATLAB it would be `'%.6e %.6e %.6e %d %d\n'`  This is what I have so far but it gives me floats for all numbers: `str_q = str((final_BCT[r]).astype(float))[1 : -1]` The first 3 numbers look fine, I just want the last 2 to be integers.

[picture of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lio09.png)

Comment: You want to look into Python format strings

Comment: Please apply the image as text code block.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thanks for your help.